# How i can handle Pending_Ap status change,Email confirmation on email change?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Are there functionality to handle **PENDING_AP** status change to **UNLOCKED**,and email confirmation when changing to new one?

1. I register user and **WSO** sends email to set password, then changes status to **UNLOCKED** after setting password
2. When i change my email in **WSO2**,it sends confirmation post to my email. How i can handle click to **CONFIRM** button

Comment: Could you please elaborate more about "When i change my email in WSO2,it sends confirmation post to my email. How i can handle click to CONFIRM button"?

Comment: @ShanChathusandaJayathilaka When i change my email in wso2, i get message to my new email and i have to confirm it in order to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are referring to the [account pending status](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/pending-account-status/#adding-accountstate-claim) feature in WSO2 IS.
It supports in three user onboarding scenarios as mentioned in the doc:

1. Self-registration
2. On-boarding users with Ask password
3. On-boarding user with Email Verification

In these scenarios initially onboarded user is locked and, upon some verification, the account will be unlocked. That account status changes are tracked in account state claim. That should be the functionality you have mentioned in point one.

In point two, you may be referring to [Enable Email Account Verification for an Updated Email Address feature](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/enable-email-account-verification-for-an-updated-email-address/#step-01-configure-the-email-adapter-to-send-emails). In this scenario, we do not lock the user account. It just waiting to change the user's email until he/she approves the newly changed email. The new email is kept in **Verification Pending Email claim** until the user confirms it.

Since user account locking is not required for email changing, PENDING_AP status change to UNLOCKED doesn't have any sense in this user scenario.

Comment: Thanks! About second scenario, does wso2 have services to handle new email confirmation?

Comment: https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-governance/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.recovery/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/recovery/handler/UserEmailVerificationHandler.java This handler is responsible for this functionality. https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/7183 will be helpful for you to understand the feature